# Speeding up code doing random sampling

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, random

I have a particular probability distribution (that is a function of a parameter $\phi$), that I would like to sample from and then do a listplot for that function.

Here is the code that I came up with:

```
m = 1;
\[Omega] = 1;
\[HBar] = 1;
fockelements = 8;

quadratures = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
    1/Sum[1/k!, {k, 0, fockelements}] Abs[
       Sum[(\[Alpha] E^(I \[Phi]))^n/\[Sqrt](n!) 1/
          Sqrt[2^n n!] ((m \[Omega])/(\[Pi] \[HBar]))^(1/
            4) Exp[-((m \[Omega] z^2)/(2 \[HBar]))] HermiteH[n, 
          Sqrt[(m \[Omega])/\[HBar]] z], {n, 0, 
         fockelements}]]^2, {z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] /. {\
\[Alpha] -> 1};

points = 3;
\[Phi]list = Subdivide[2 \[Pi], points];
data = RandomVariate[quadratures /. \[Phi] -> #] & /@ \[Phi]list
ListPlot[data]
```

It seems to work but it's very slow. Origionally the code had a few functions-in-functions, and I tried putting everything in a compact form in hopes that it would speed-up, but it's still too slow.

Ideally I'd like to sample something like 1000 points, while right now it takes a very long time to do even 100 samplings.

**EDIT:**
Not sure it helps to mention this but here are some warnings I get when I run my code:

[image]

Maybe this will make it more obvious what the issue is.

**EDIT2:**
Just mentioning that I added a normalization constant to the code above as suggested by @JimB. (The code is still slow after normalization).

Comment: Please provide all definitions to run this.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thanks for letting me know, I forgot to say what the variables are.

Comment: To make the function you give into a pdf that integrates to 1 you'll need to multiply it by `Exp[-1]` or use the `Method->"Normalize"` option.  The former would probably be better.

Comment: Your distribution is so very, very close to a Normal distribution with mean $\sqrt{2}\cos(\phi)$ and variance 3/4.  Would you give your rationale for needing such a subtly different distribution?  (I don't doubt you have a good rationale.  I'm just curious.)

Comment: @JimB, thanks for the help. It should be normalized already so I guess I have a bug somewhere...

Comment: Also, the distribution is normal in the limit the sum goes to infinity. I'm doing this example first because it's the easiest to confirm visually that it behaves as expected. I have much more unusual looking distributions that I will look at after this. (and that's why I need it to not be so slow).

Comment: @JimB, also code is still slow after that change.

Comment: Normal in the limit of what?  The first four moments for this particular distribution for any value of $\phi$ between 0 and $2\pi$ matches almost perfectly the first 4 moments of a normal distribution (again with mean and variance $\sqrt{2}\cos(\phi)$ and 3/4, respectively.  My point is that the deviation from a normal is so small that with a sample of size 10,000 there's no way you could notice a difference.

Comment: In the limit where the sum goes to infinity. I am aware that this particular distribution is super close to a normal distribution, that's why I'm doing this as a first step. (to see this nromal distribution as a check that I didn't make a mistake). There are other functions that are similar that I would like to plot with this method that are certainly not normal distributions.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.  The multiplier should be 8!/109601 rather than `Exp[-1]`.  If $n$ in the sum goes from 0 to $n_0$, then the multiplier should be $1/\sum_{k=0}^{n_0}(1/k!)$.  As the number of terms goes up then the multiplier approaches `Exp[-1]`.

Comment: Ohh, I see, the issue is that I have a finite amount of elements in my series. I'll use the more general normalization that you suggest (of 1/$\sum 1/k!$)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118400/discussion-between-jimb-and-steven-sagona).

Answer (score 4):

This is more of an extended comment.  Here is a slight modification of your code:

```
parms = {m -> 1, ω -> 1, ℏ -> 1, α -> 1, n0 -> 8};

quadratures = ProbabilityDistribution[(1/Sum[1/k!, {k, 0, n0}]) *
  Abs[Sum[(α E^(I ϕ))^n/√(n!) 1/Sqrt[2^n n!] ((m ω)/(π ℏ))^(1/4) *
  Exp[-((m ω z^2)/(2 ℏ))] HermiteH[n, Sqrt[(m ω)/ℏ] z], {n, 0, n0}]]^2,
  {z, -∞, ∞}] /. parms;

points = 10;
ϕlist = Subdivide[2 π, points];
AbsoluteTiming[Quiet[data = RandomVariate[quadratures /. ϕ -> #, 1000] & /@ ϕlist;]]
(* {5.89363, Null} *)
```

So that takes about 6 seconds to generate 10,000 samples (1,000 for each of 10 values of $\phi$.  Getting 100,000 samples (10,000 samples for each of the 10 values of $\phi$) takes only 7 seconds. Just doing one at a time as your code is doing will be much slower.  (I have to imagine that getting just a single random sample from each value of $\phi$ can't be of much use.)

The CDF when $\phi=2$ is

```
CDF[quadratures /. parms /. ϕ -> 2, z]
```

[image: CDF of quadratures distribution with phi = 2]

There likely isn't a nice closed-form inverse function to obtain random samples so I think there's not much you can do to speed things up other than to take multiple samples for each value of $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks JimB. Now I need to figure out how to put this result into the correct form to be plottable.

Comment: So far I tried data = Riffle[ 
     RandomVariate[quadratures /. \[Phi] -> #, 1000], #, {1, 1000, 
      2}] & /@ \[Phi]list;  and then ListPlot[ Partition[Flatten[data], 2]]  - but there's some bug where it only does some of the data correctly.

Comment: Not understanding what kind of plot you want.  (Each row in my example represents a different value of $\phi$.)  Getting histograms for each is found with `Histogram[#, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"] & /@ data`.

Comment: I did it with: data = Riffle[ 
       RandomVariate[quadratures /. \[Phi] -> #, 10], #, {2, -1, 
        2}] & /@ \[Phi]list;]]
ListPlot[ Partition[Flatten[Reverse[data, 2]], 2]

Comment: Every 1000 elements pulls from the same value of theta, so I just need to generate a list where each element in the 1000 has its own associated theta value (ie, {{0, Rand[F[0]]}, {0, Rand[F[0]]},...(one-thousand samples with theta =0),..(more samples for other theta values),...,{pi, Rand[F[pi]]},...,{pi, Rand[F[pi]]}}